# How to use javaScript TimeSheet Plugin in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular5, timesheet.js

In my project I need to use exactly the same plugin in Angular 5 as this TimeSheet https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Table-Based-jQuery-Calendar-Schedule-Plugin-TimeSheet.html.
 But I haven't found a module like this and need to import and use it in project. How can I import and use it in my project?

Comment: you can use ng2-timesheet .Here i provide link below
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-timesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just attach *TimeSheet javaScript* file and `jQuery` to the scripts in your angular configuration file.

```
scripts: [ 
    'yourRelativePath/TimeSheet.js' 
]
```

Then `declare var $` to force compiler not to argue on the `$` variable or add `@types/jQuery` into `devDependencies`:

```
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

and

```
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

With *Angular/Typescript* you can use every Javascript file, cause TypeScript files will be compiled into Javascript, one thing is just to let compiler to pass your code.

Comment: @Hovhannes Gevorgyan, Apres Hovo jan